# How using to get classes in upper / ucfirst / lower case different format?

Tags: laravel, stub

In laravel 10 app using stubs I have problem with first letter of a class as having
in stubs/controller.plain.stub file classes which must be used in different format like "Class", "class", "CLASS",

I tried to use

```
Str::ucfirst
```

method :

```
namespace {{ namespace }};

use {{ rootNamespace }}Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Create{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Update{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}Request;
use App\Http\Resources\{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}Resource;
use App\Repositories\{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}CrudRepository;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\DBTransactionInterface;

class {{ class }}Controller extends Controller
{
    protected ${{ class }}CrudRepository;
    protected $dbTransaction;

    public function __construct({{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}CrudRepository ${{ class }}CrudRepository, DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction)
    {
        $this->{{ class }}CrudRepository = ${{ class }}CrudRepository;
        $this->dbTransaction = $dbTransaction;
    }
```

But with command :

```
php artisan make:controller --type=plain ProductController
```

Different file I need :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Create{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Update{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}Request;
use App\Http\Resources\{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}Resource;
use App\Library\AppCustomException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\{{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}CrudRepository;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\DBTransactionInterface;

class ProductControllerController extends Controller
{


    protected $ProductControllerCrudRepository;
    protected $dbTransaction;

    public function __construct({{ Str::ucfirst(class) }}CrudRepository $ProductControllerCrudRepository, DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction)
    {
        $this->ProductControllerCrudRepository = $ProductControllerCrudRepository;
        $this->dbTransaction = $dbTransaction;
    }


Str::ucfirst(class)
```

- was not replaced and sure I need

  ProductController

but not :

```
ProductControllerController
```

If there is a way to tune it someway?

Comment: just replace class {{ class }}Controller extends Controller with class {{ class }} extends Controller, or am i missing something? then you would have the {{ Str::ucfirst(class) }} not working, right?

Comment: i think you will have to create an additional variable for {{ Str::ucfirst(class) }} following the steps here https://medium.com/@ariadoos/laravel-custom-file-stubs-ed32f046ea81 may help

Comment: the stubs are **NOT** Blade files